# How to delete all s3 folders except most recent n folders?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We deploy have a JavaScript project that is built and deployed regularly to an S3 folder. Each release is pushed to a unique folder that uses a guid for the

- name: releases/[guid]/

Our releases are manual so they do not follow any sort of predictable schedule. We would like to create an automated process that cleans-up old releases. The process should delete all except the most recent n-number of releases.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would write a lambda for this.

Comment: Because guids don't contain a timestamp, you'll likely have to list the `releases/` prefix of your bucket, identify one object per release (maybe there's a single `package.json` file, for example), filter out the other objects from the list, then sort on LastModified to determine the prefixes that you need to purge.